# Concatenate two ideas

Tags: grammar

I have two doubts in the following sentence:

Plastic has the lowest production cost but the best efficiency against other materials.

- The first one is if it's correctly written because I want to say that plastic has lowest production cost and the best efficiency at the same time. So if there's a better way to write it, please tell me.
- The second one is if I should use "and" instead of "but" and why.

Any other suggestions are welcome. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that you should use *and*, because low production cost and best efficiency are similar ideas (not contrasting). But you should probably say *compared with* instead of *against*.